# Positioning dynamic buttons with absolute position in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a set of `buttons`, which is being added via `Jquery`. Now I want to `position` these buttons exactly `above the element` by clicking, so I'm trying to get position of the element and putting the css property to the buttons.

Problem is I'm not able to position appropriately, I've made the `base element's position` as `relative` and the `buttons` as `absolute`, even I tried putting relative, fixed but its not working.

For example,

HTML elements where I want to place buttons, I'm calling it through class `nitssection`:

```
<div class="section nitssection" data-nitsid="6">
    <div class="container">
....
    </div>
</div>
```

Position of base element:

```
.nitssection {
     position: relative;
}
```

Now placing buttons:

```
<div id="#" class="clearfix nitsoption" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default sorthandle">
        Sort <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
        Edit <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
        Clone <i class="fa fa-clone"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
        Delete <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

`id` of the `elements` are `dynamic` and following is the Jquery where I'm trying to position the button:

```
$('.nitssection').click(function(e) {
    var nitsbutton = $(this).data("nitsid");
    var x=$(this).offset();
    var y=$(window).innerWidth();
    var xcenter= x.top-30;
    var ycenter=y/2;
    $('#' + nitsbutton).css({
        'position': "absolute"
        , 'top': xcenter
        , 'left': ycenter-150
        , 'z-index': "99999"

    }).fadeIn(400).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

As you can see in the [following link](http://noeticitservices.com/JSEditor/), once you click to the section part, the buttons are being displayed below.

Comment: do you want to add button above nitssection or inside nitssection's container?

Comment: @Pratham above nitssection.

Comment: okay so on click of nitssection div another div should come up above nitssection div which will contain buttons. right?

Comment: @Pratham yes. I'm using `Jquery` to `append` those div to `nitssection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution,

I was calculating the `top` and adding the top value to the generated elements. when we add top value in `absolute position` it calculates the top value of the  `parent element`, so in my question I removed the top value being calculated with offset value. Following will be removed from the code:

```
 var x=$(this).offset();
 var xcenter= x.top-30;
```

So my final code looks like:

```
$('.nitssection').click(function(e) {
    var nitsbutton = $(this).data("nitsid");
    var y=$(window).innerWidth();
    var ycenter=y/2-200;
    $('#' + nitsbutton).css({
        'position' : "absolute"
        , 'top': -35
        , 'left': ycenter
        , 'z-index': "99999"

    }).fadeIn(400).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

Hope it helps someone.. :)